# Does shutting down a broker, moves the replicas on that broker to a new broker automatically?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with 6 brokers and over 60 topics, with a replication factor of either 2 or 3. We plan to replace all the existing brokers with new nodes.

I have 2 questions:

1. Once we add 6 new nodes to the cluster making it total 12 nodes, and shut down old brokers one by one, will the replicas move to new brokers automatically?
2. If not, we will have to move them using the reassignment tool, in that case do we need to move `__consumer_offsets` topic as well, or Kafka will take care of that itself?

Comment: @amethytsic can you answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, replicas are not moved automatically. Before shutting down the old brokers, you'll have to reassign replicas using the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion for the details how to use this tool
2. Yes, you will need to move all partitions, including the internal ones (`__consumer_offsets` and `__transaction_state`)

Comment: `__transaction_state` topic was not there with kafka 0.10.1.1 but I had to move `__consumer_offsets` manually. Thanks  @mickael-maison